# Why when getting the volume parameter value the volume is so loud?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class BackToMainMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objsToDisable;
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;

    public static bool gameSceneLoaded;

    private void Awake()
    {
        gameSceneLoaded = true;
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume")) * 20);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (Time.timeScale == 0)
            {
                DisableEnableUiTexts(true);
                SceneManager.UnloadSceneAsync(0);
                Cursor.visible = false;
                Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                MenuController.LoadSceneForSavedGame = false;
                SceneManager.LoadScene(0, LoadSceneMode.Additive);
                SceneManager.sceneLoaded += SceneManager_sceneLoaded;

                Cursor.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void SceneManager_sceneLoaded(Scene arg0, LoadSceneMode arg1)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", Mathf.Log(0.0001f) * 20);
        DisableEnableUiTexts(false);
    }

    private void DisableEnableUiTexts(bool enabled)
    {
        foreach (GameObject go in objsToDisable)
        {
            if (go.name == "Cameras")
            {
                foreach(Transform child in go.transform)
                {
                    if(child.name == "Main Camera")
                    {
                        if (enabled == false)
                        {
                            child.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            child.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                go.SetActive(enabled);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When running the game the Main Menu scene start then when making a new game the Game scene is loaded and then here in the Start I'm getting the Main Menu volume float parameter and set it to the Game Music volume.

```
void Start()
        {
            audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume")) * 20);
        }
```

When in the Main Menu scene the volume is -4.01 dB of the main menu music.

[Main Menu music volume is -4.01 dB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXtMv.jpg)

Then when it's getting the volume of the main menu and set it to the Game music volume the Game music volume is 35.99 dB and I can't figure out why it's setting the volume to so high value ?

[The game music volume value is 35.99 dB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZMDZ.jpg)

Could be the calculation to get the volume in the Start is wrong ?
It should not be Log10 ? Or not * 20 ?

```
audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume")) * 20);
```

How come it's getting from -4.01 dB to 35.99 dB ?

This script in the Mein Menu scene is setting the music and sfx volumes of the main menu using ui sliders :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Audio;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using System.Linq;

public class Settings : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private AudioSource[] audioSources;
    public AudioMixer audioMixer;
    public TMP_Dropdown resolutionDropdown;
    public TMP_Dropdown qualityDropdown;
    public Text musicText;
    public Text sfxText;
    public Slider[] audioSliders;
    public Toggle fullScreenToggle;

    private Resolution[] resolutions;

    private void Awake()
    {
        audioSources = GetComponents<AudioSource>();

        resolutionDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("resolutionvalue", resolutionDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        qualityDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<int>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("qualityvalue", qualityDropdown.value);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));

        fullScreenToggle.onValueChanged.AddListener(new UnityAction<bool>(index =>
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("fullscreen", boolToInt(fullScreenToggle.isOn));
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

        }));
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        qualityDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("qualityvalue");

        var resolutions = Screen.resolutions.Where(resolution => resolution.refreshRate == 60).ToArray();
        resolutionDropdown.ClearOptions();

        List<string> options = new List<string>();

        int currentResolutionIndex = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < resolutions.Length; i++)
        {
            string option = resolutions[i].width + " x " + resolutions[i].height;
            options.Add(option);

            if(resolutions[i].width == Screen.currentResolution.width &&
                resolutions[i].height == Screen.currentResolution.height)
            {
                currentResolutionIndex = i;
            }
        }

        resolutionDropdown.AddOptions(options);
        resolutionDropdown.value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("resolutionvalue", currentResolutionIndex);
        resolutionDropdown.RefreshShownValue();

        float musicvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume");
        float sfxvolume = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenusfxvolume");

        musicText.text = musicvolume.ToString();
        sfxText.text = sfxvolume.ToString();
        audioSliders[0].value = musicvolume / 100f;
        audioSliders[1].value = sfxvolume / 100f;

        fullScreenToggle.isOn = intToBool(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("fullscreen", 0));
        
    }

    public void SetResolution(int resolutionIndex)
    {
        if (resolutions != null)
        {
            Resolution resolution = resolutions[resolutionIndex];
            Screen.SetResolution(resolution.width, resolution.height, Screen.fullScreen);
        }
    }

    public void SetMusicVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        musicText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
    }

    public void SetSfxVolume(float volume)
    {
        audioMixer.SetFloat("mainmenusfxvolume", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
        sfxText.text = Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero).ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmenusfxvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));

        if (!audioSources[1].isPlaying)
            audioSources[1].Play();
    }

    public void SetQuality(int qualityIndex)
    {
        QualitySettings.SetQualityLevel(qualityIndex);
    }

    public void SetFullscreen(bool isFullscreen)
    {
        Screen.fullScreen = isFullscreen;        
    }

    int boolToInt(bool val)
    {
        if (val)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }

    bool intToBool(int val)
    {
        if (val != 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

The SetMusicVolume is called by the slider event of the main menu music.

Comment: What code sets main menu volume to -4.01dB? ```Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume")) * 20``` or ```Mathf.Log(0.0001f) * 20```, somewhere else in the code or manual setting in gui?

Comment: @MarkSouls I edited my question and added the script that set the main menu volume for the music.   I'm using a ui slider to change the music volume in the main menu. and save the changes to the PlayerPrefs then I'm trying to read the volume value of the main menu music back from the PlayerPrefs in the BackToMainMenu script.

Comment: It looks like you multiply the value used in the formula by 100 when you save it, so you'd want to divide it by 100 before applying your formula again.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Oh, This line : PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)); So if when applying it back I was doing * 100 instead * 20 it was working ? Just for knowing. I will change it but this is the problem right ?

Comment: @RetiredNinja Why in the audioMixer.SetFloat I'm using Log10 and * 20 and in the PlayerPrefs.SetFloat I'm using Round and * 100 ? Could I use Log10 and * 20 in both places ?

Comment: Let's say volume is 10 here: `audioMixer.SetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);` It is then saved as 1000 here: `PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume", (float)Math.Round(volume * 100, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));` When you want t use it in the formula you need to get it from the prefs and divide by 100 to get back the value that was used in the formula before. You don't need to change the formula but you need to make sure you pass it the same value to get the same result. Why you aren't just saving the value unchanged is something you'd have to ask yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are mixing some of the string parameters.

In your first script you're setting the audio mixer `gamemusicvolume` parameter like this:

```
    audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", Mathf.Log10(PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume")) * 20);
```

And then in the second script you're setting the audio mixer `mainmenumusicvolume` parameter instead of the `gamemusicvolume` parameter.

```
    audioMixer.SetFloat("mainmenumusicvolume", Mathf.Log10(volume) * 20);
```

Moreover, later in the first script you set the `gamemusicvolume` to an even lower value:

```
    audioMixer.SetFloat("gamemusicvolume", Mathf.Log(0.0001f) * 20);
```

All in all, this code feels wrong and overcomplicated. Why do you save a value and then do Log * 20 manipulations? Why not just save the actual value that you want, keep your code simple.